# Firebase Push Notification to different group of tokens

Tags: javascript, firebase

I would like to send notification to different token groups.

My RealTime Database look like this

- fcm-token
- - HHE Data
- - - (Token)
- - HHE Other
- - - (Token)

this code only work with one of the fcm-token groups.

```
enter code heregconst functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.notification= functions.database.ref('notification/{id}').onWrite(evt => {
  const payload = {
    notification:{
        title : 'Ny person på listen',
        body : '',
        badge : '1',
        sound : 'default'
    }
  };

  return admin.database().ref('fcm-token/HHE Data').once('value').then(allToken => {
    if(allToken.val()){
        console.log('token available');
        const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload);
    }else{
        console.log('No token available');
    }
  });
});
```

How do I get what the {id} is?

the Path "notification/{id}" is specific outside of the code
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK7cx.png)

but I would like to use it like this:

```
return admin.database().ref('fcm-token/' + id).once('value').then(allToken => {
  if(allToken.val()){
    console.log('token available');
    const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload);
  }else{
    console.log('No token available');
  }
});
```

The only solution I have come up with is to do it manually for each group.
and create function for each, because path it check is specific outside of the code. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK7cx.png)

like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.notification = functions.database.ref('notification/HHE Data/{id}').onCreate(evt => {
    const payload = {
        notification:{
            title : 'Ny person på listen',
            body : '',
            badge : '1',
            sound : 'default'
        }
    };

      return admin.database().ref('fcm-token/HHE Data').once('value').then(allToken => {
        if(allToken.val()){
            console.log('token available');
            const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload);
        }else{
            console.log('No token available');
        }
    });

    return admin.database().ref('notification').once('value');
});
```